# Linkedin Api is not working properly

Tags: uwp

I have created new app(API) in LinkedIn developer platform. I was using that in my UWP app. Somehow it was not working as expected so I have removed the app and created new app(API) in LinkedIn developer platform (LinkedIn API). Now the problem is, when I am trying to access user profile/share the content  is throwing 401 error saying that the consumer key (which is the older one) is disabled.

However I am using new clientid (consumer key) and client secrete from the newly created API. I have cleared the solution, cleared the temp data, everything. Still it is using the older key to get the user data.

Comment: Have you tried using the LinkedInService from the UWP Community Toolkit?

Comment: I am using UWP community Toolkit only, here is my code,
 var oAuthTokens = new LinkedInOAuthTokens
            {
                ClientId = ClientId,ClientSecret = SecretId,CallbackUri = Callbackurl
            };
            var succeeded = LinkedInService.Instance.Initialize(oAuthTokens, LinkedInPermissions.ReadBasicProfile | LinkedInPermissions.WriteShare);
            var loggedIn = await LinkedInService.Instance.LoginAsync();
            if (loggedIn)
            { var profile = await LinkedInService.Instance.GetUserProfileAsync(); }

Comment: below is the exception i got for this line
var profile = await LinkedInService.Instance.GetUserProfileAsync(); 

An exception of type 'Microsoft.Toolkit.Uwp.Services.Exceptions.RequestFailedException' occurred in XamlBrewer.Uwp.SplitViewNavigation.exe but was not handled in user code

Additional information: Request failed with status code 401 and reason '{

  "errorCode": 0,

  "message": "[unauthorized]. Consumer key <key> is disabled",

  "requestId": "R3F6M4FCM1",

  "status": 401,

  "timestamp": 1494997135272

}'

Comment: strange but i ran the same code same application from another machine and it worked. I don't get it, why it is not working for my machine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

UnInstalling the deployed app in my machine resolved the issue, now it is using the newer key to get user profile. i think it was some cache issue or something, don't know the exact reason but it is working